# automatic thumbnail slider using jquery : cannot add animation effects

Tags: jquery

i am trying to make an automatic image slider using jquery. i'm using an unordered list as the source of images. i used the basic logic that after a certain delay each

would be detached from the list and so on. this is happening but its not happening smoothly.. i tried using animate function but that didnt work either . i even added the easing option in the animate function and still it didnt work. can anyone help me ? thanx in advance

here is my code
function rotate_images()
{
 var i=1;

var _rotate = function()
      {
    setTimeout(function()
      {
      var li=$('#li'+i);
      $('#li'+i).animate({'display':'none'},1000,'swing',function(){$(this).remove();});

```
 if(i<5)
 {
  i++;
 _rotate();           
 }
 else
 {
  i=1;
  _rotate();
 }
 },2000);
```

}; 
 _rotate();
}

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the jquery cycle plugin to accomplish this:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Just tell it the parent object and you can customize how it works and use easing effects etc..